# How to re-order items in Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
var list = [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse' 'rabbit']
```

Now, I want to remove one item in the array, cat.

```
list.splice(1, 1)
```

Now my array looks like this

```
list = [ 'dog', 'horse', 'rabbit' ]
```

What I want to do is re-order it based on the item that was removed, so for example

```
list = [ 'horse', 'rabbit', 'dog']
```

How would I achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: "Re-order it based on the item that was removed" ← what does this mean?

Comment: So since cat was removed, instead of showing 'dog', 'horse', 'rabbit' - I'd like to show 'horse', 'rabbit' 'dog' - dog being the last

Comment: I vote "most confusing question - september"

Comment: But in what way does the removal of 'cat' imply, or dictate, that the order becomes `['horse','rabbit','dog']`? What would the order be if 'horse' was removed? Or 'rabbit'? And why?

Comment: lol - think of it this way.  Basically i want everything before cat to go now at the end, but in the order they were in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```js
var list = [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'rabbit'] 

function reorderSlice(index) {
  var start = list.slice(0, index)
  var end = list.slice(index + 1)
  return end.concat(start)
}

console.log(reorderSlice(1))
```

Comment: actually it's better now. there was no need to splice as we are slicing the array twice

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the new list to start after the removed element, and append all the items that were before it:

```
var list = [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'rabbit'] ;
var itemIndex = 1; // Index of 'cat' (removed item)
list = list.slice(itemIndex+1).concat(list.slice(0,itemIndex));

console.log(list); // ["horse", "rabbit", "dog"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The code will splice the all items up to the nth position. Then add them back to the end of the list except the nth item.

```
var removed = list.splice(0, n);
list.push(removed.splice(0, removed.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny the way you express the question... You might do as follows;

```js
function funkyDeleteItem(a,i){
  return a.slice(i+1).concat(a.slice(0,i));
}

var a = [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'rabbit'],
    b = funkyDeleteItem(a,1);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use an `Array.sort()` function to perform sorting based on whatever criteria you'd like using a <=> styled function

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(
    function(left, right) {
        return left - right;
    }
);
// returns: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb8fkfsm/)